# How to add CSS to the HTML file that I send through e-mail with Python

Tags: python, html, css

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Test"
msg['From'] = GMAIL
msg['To'] = EMAIL_TO_SEND_TO

html = open("template.html").read().format(Name="swix")
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part2)

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(user=GMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
        connection.sendmail(GMAIL, EMAIL_TO_SEND_TO, msg.as_string())
```

This works fine and sends a mail with the html, however, I do not get the CSS that I have applied. Any idea how to fix that?

The name of the CSS file is style.css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to send an e-mail with formatted HTML, if you search for that even here on stackoverflow you will get some results that tell you that external CSS stylesheets are rarely supported. This means that the "style.css" file will not be sent with your e-mail in any way.

The solution to your problem is to create a custom html template with inline style CSS added to your html. i.e. (<div style="color:blue;background:pink;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;>Blue 16px Sized Bolded Text On a Pink Background) and send that in the e-mail.

Please note that not all CSS is supported for e-mails - I won't link to pages that list all the HTML and CSS supported, but you can easily find multiple resources out there to help you out.

Comment: Oh. That would explain why even after trying for hours to do the CSS internally/inline, I was not able to do fancy 3D Text Effects. Ugh. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you found that helpful, if that answers your question, please be sure to mark the answer as the solution ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement inline style CSS to manifest CSS in emails.
The reason is that most email providers support this style today, which means you're likely to get the best results without running into any formatting trouble with inline style.

I'm assuming your CSS in template.html file is included in head. There's a great API that you can simply call to transfer them into inline style HTML.
Please check this out: https://inlinestyler.visigo.com/styler/api/

Once you get the inline style HTML response from the API you can directly put them in your SMTP body.

Comment: Since this is a Python question, a Python package like [css-inline](https://pypi.org/project/css-inline/) or [pynliner](https://pythonhosted.org/pynliner/) might be a better solution than a web API.